# Should a comma be placed before or after the conjunction 'and'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Originating from a comment on one of the SE sites.

Which one is correctly punctuated?

1. "Nothing personal and, welcome to *.SE"
2. "Nothing personal, and welcome to *.SE"

My understanding is that we use the comma wherever we have to pause, in speech and to help with connecting related phrases together. I was dumbfounded, because both sentences seemed equally cool (yes, I was trying to sound cool in the comment). I am willing to accept omission of the comma entirely as well, if 'and' is not followed by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comma is required in that position.  If comma is used, it should be before "and".

In speech you might pause

> It's nothing personal{falling intonation, pause} and welcome...{rising intonation}

The "and" is part of an intonation group with "welcome" and so the comma goes before, not after.